# SQL query: SUM values up to the current record

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

Basically, having this table:

```
12.10
 2.35
21.45
35.26
```

I want to, in each record, calculate the sum of all previous records, like this:

```
12.10 | 12.10
 2.35 | 14.45
21.45 | 35.90
35.26 | 71.16
```

Comment: How do you know in which order they should be summed?

Comment: Well that's the thing. Usually I order them by date (there's a date field), but some records have the same date. Is it possible to do it with something like ROW_NUMBER() ?

Comment: if not, just assume there's an ID field and order by that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called a running total.

If you have a datetime column you can use something like this:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.transactiondatetime, amount,
(
 SELECT SUM(amount) 
 FROM dbo.table1 as t1 
 WHERE t1.transactiondatetime <= t0.transactiondatetime
) AS balance
FROM dbo.table1 AS t0
```

Comment: I'm going to go with this one because it avoids the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you have two columns, a primary key called `id` and a column called `value` then you can use this:

```
SELECT T1.id, SUM(T2.value)
FROM table1 T1
JOIN table1 T2
ON T2.id <= T1.id
GROUP BY T1.id
```

If you don't have any unique identifier (why not?) then you can use ROW_NUMBER to create one.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use window functions

```
SELECT id, data_size, 
SUM(data_size) OVER (ORDER BY ID) total_size
FROM files;
```

then the result is as follows

```
ID         DATA_SIZE  TOTAL_SIZE
---------- ---------- ----------
104427       3977       3977
104428     118948     122925
104429        847     123772
104430       2145     125917
104431       2688     128605
104432       3798     132403
104433       3110     135513
104434       5534     141047
104435       3956     145003

9 rows selected.
```

As you can see, it sums up all the previous DATA_SIZE column values

Source: http://etutorials.org/SQL/Mastering+Oracle+SQL/Chapter+14.+Advanced+Analytic+SQL/14.3+Windowing+Functions/